# What is the hidden argument being passed to my `MethodType`?

Tags: python

I recently came across [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498147-weakmethod/) for making a "weakmethod" and thought it was the bees' knees; but there seems to be a mystery argument being passed to the resulting `MethodType` function that i can't seem to find:

```
from weakref import proxy
from types import MethodType

class Foo(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('foo_'):
            return MethodType(super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(name), proxy(self), self.__class__)
        else:
            return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(name)

class Bar(Foo):
    def my_func(self, a, b):
        print a, b

    def foo_my_func(self, a, b):
        print 'FF Victory Theme'

>>> bar = Bar()
>>> bar.my_func(1, 2)
1 2
>>> weakmethod = bar.foo_my_func
>>> weakmethod(2, 3) # Or `bar.foo_my_func(2, 3)`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#160>", line 1, in <module>
    weakmethod(2, 3)
TypeError: foo_my_func() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

What is this 4th argument that's being passed?

Comment: What is `proxy()` here? Is it `weakref.proxy()`?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I've added the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(name)` to access the `foo_my_func` method. This **already** returns a `MethodType` object. You then *wrap this object **again***.

So your returned object passes in `proxy(self)` to the wrapped method, which passes in *another* `self` argument. You started with `a, b`, and end up with `self, proxy(self), a, b`.

The recipe you linked to uses a decorator instead; this decorator is executed *at class definition time*, and wraps the function object. It is itself a descriptor, so it handles all the wrapping directly.

You'll want to either *unwrap* the result of `super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(name)` or don't use `__getattribute__` at all.

Unwrapping can be done with accessing the `__func__` attribute on a method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(name)
        if name.startswith('foo_'):
            return MethodType(attr.__func__, proxy(self), self.__class__)
        return attr
```

Not using `__getattribute__` is done by just accessing the `__dict__` mapping on the class directly:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('foo_'):
            for cls in type(self).__mro__:
                if name in cls.__dict__:
                    return MethodType(cls.__dict__[name], proxy(self), self.__class__)
        return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

where `type(self).__mro__` lets you iterate over the class and it's base classes in method resolution order to manually search for the method.

Comment: Did you mean `self, proxy(self), a, b`?

Comment: @NoobSaibot: it doesn't really matter, the method wrappers don't care how it was obtained, but yes.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for(even if my weakmethod idea was a dead end). Thanks.